# AWS CloudFrontをbotoで設定、その際にGrant Read Permissions on Bucket:Yes にしたい

Tags: python, aws

AWS CloudFrontを Pythonから `boto` を使って設定しています。
しかし、以下の設定ができません。
botoでは出来ないのでしょうか？

`Grant Read Permissions on Bucket: Yes, Update Bucket Policy`

Comment: 使用しているコマンド、オプション等が無いとアドバイスし辛いかと思います

Answer (score 1):

マネージメントコンソール上での該当の設定は、
1) CloudFront上でオリジナルアイデンティティを作成
2) オリジナルアイデンティティからのアクセスを許可するポリシーをS3バケットに設定
にAPIとしては分かれています。

1) は、botoの場合はcloudfrontのorigin_access_identity関連のAPIを使って実現できるはずです。
http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/cloudfront.html

Comment: 2) がうまく出来ていないのだと思うのですが、うまく連携が取れず未だに完成していません。
AWS Webコンソールで出来ることをbotoで実現するための方法を、botoのドキュメンテーションから探し出すのが難しいと感じています。